# No logro cambiar los valores de un array asociativo en php con laravel

Tags: php, array, laravel-7, laravel-livewire

Estoy haciendo un calendario de entradas y salidas para gestionar la limpieza de apartamentos vacacionales, para ello he creado un array asociativo, luego de crearlo necesito cambiar de alguna manera todos los datos de los días que están entre una entrada y una salida a "ocupado" y de ninguna manera lo he podido lograr
este es el código de la creación del array

```
$calendario = [];
        
        foreach ($casas as $casa) {
            $calendario +=[$casa->nombre => array()];

            foreach ($all_days as $day) {
                
                foreach ($entradas as $entrada) {
                    //guarda las entradas en el array
                    if ($entrada->entrada == $day->format('Y-m-d') && $entrada->casa->nombre == $casa->nombre) {
                        
                        $calendario[$casa->nombre][$day->format('Y-m-d')] = [
                            "ocupado"   => true,
                            "entrada"   => $entrada,
                            "salida"    => false
                        ];
                    }else{
                        $calendario[$casa->nombre][$day->format('Y-m-d')] = [
                            "ocupado"   => false,
                            "salida"    => false
                        ];
                    }
                    //guarda las salidas en el array
                    if ($entrada->salida == $day->format('Y-m-d') && $entrada->casa->nombre == $casa->nombre) {
                        
                        $calendario[$casa->nombre][$day->format('Y-m-d')] = [
                            "salida"    => true,
                            "ocupado"   => true,
                            "entrada"   => $entrada,
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, el array es creado sactisfactoriamente, el problema es a la
hora de cambiar los valores en el array

```
$flag = false;
        
        foreach ($calendario as $casita) {

            foreach ($casita as $dia ) {

                if (count($dia)>2) {
                    if ($dia["entrada"]) {
                        $flag=true;
                    }else{
                        $flag=false;
                    }
                }

                if($flag){
                    $dia["ocupado"]= true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Aquí la estructura del array:

```
[casas => [dias => [entrada, salida, ocupado]]
```

[image: Estructura del array]

Estoy tratando de cambiar los valores de "ocupado" a "true" en los días que hay entre una entrada y una salida para representarlo de mejor manera en la vista

El problema principal es que este código no me da error, simplemente los valores no cambian a true, todos los valores están igual que en el array original.

Estaré muy agradecido si me pueden ayudar de alguna manera, llevo horas mirando el mismo código y buscando, pero no encuentro nada.

Comment: Prueba con `foreach ($casita as &$dia ) {`

Comment: O prueba cambiando esto: `$dia["ocupado"]= true;` por esto: `$calendario[$casita][$dia]["ocupado"]= true;`

Comment: al cambiar `$dia["ocupado"] = true; ` me dice Illegal offset type

y al cabiar el foreach a `` foreach ($casita as &$dia ) { `` no veo ningun cambio, pero aun así gracias, seguiré intentandolo

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude resolver, la solución es esta, el problema principal estaba en que al ser array asociativos, estaba intentando acceder al valor sin especificar la key, por eso usé el foreach se "$key => $value" y de esa manera tener la clave y el valor

EL error principal era que trataba de acceder al array sin especificar las claves del array asociativo.

```
        foreach ($calendario as $casa => $casita ) {
            $flag = false;
            foreach ($casita as $dia => $di ) {

                if (count($di)>2) {
                    if ($di["entrada"]) {
                        $flag = true;
                    }
                    if ($di["salida"]){
                        $flag = false;
                    }
                }

                if($flag == true){
                    $calendario[$casa][$dia]["ocupado"] = true;
                }
            }

        }
```